# Horizontal artifact lines on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gpu

I have horizontal artifact lines on the windows 10 desktop. They extend out of the side of a window and cause a discoloured line across the rest of the screen.

I just changed my monitor and it's only happening when the new monitor is connected. The graphics card is a 1080ti and I have an 8700k processor and 32gb ram.

Things I have already tried

1) the artifacts show up in screen shots, so I assume this rules out a problem with the monitor.

2) the issue doesn't happen with any of my old monitors.

3) the artifacts exist if I use the 1080ti or the Intel integrated graphics, so I assume this isn't cause by a dying GPU.

4) done a clean install of the graphics card driver

The new monitor is a wide-screen, the old ones were just standard 1920x1080

How can I get rid of these artifacts or at least find the cause ?

Comment: have you tried, changing the resolution or the aspect ratio of the image?, try open the nvidia control panel to use the resolutions or refresh rates that it offers

Comment: What is the resolution of the new monitor and which port do you use to connect it to the computer?